# Unable to login after changing User Password

Tags: password, encryption

My problem already listed in the forum but unfortunately it is closed and no satisfying answer available in that post. So, I am opening a new thread.

I am using ubuntu 13.04. I changed my password using `passwd` command for the user. Ex: Suppose 'XYZ' is the username I am using to login. I used this command to change the password of that user:

```
sudo passwd XYZ
```

It prompted me to enter my current password and later new password twice. everything is fine. But after changing user password successfully, I log-out and tried to log-in. I failed.

After entering my password and pressing enter, it simply goes blank for 1 or 2 seconds and re-appears the log-in screen. I am unable to enter. At the time of installation I used "encryption of home folder" option. So, I am unable to access my data from windows. (As you know that We can have read access of linux partition using some softwares).

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Boot into recovery mode, and change the password.  Boot your computer, and quickly press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key or <kbd>Escape</kbd>, which will bring up a boot menu.

When you get the grub menu, select option with recovery mode

[image]

This will take you to recovery menu. In recovery menu select option drop to root shell.

[image]

To change the password type the command below at the prompt:

```
   passwd <user_name>
```

You will be asked you to enter your new password and retype password. Type your new password.  Once done resume normal boot, and try to login.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried this but I got this error message.

Passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
Passwd: password unchanged.

Comment: Try this before the command to change the password `mount -rw -o remount /`

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. That worked for me. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you are at the login screen in Ubuntu, go in `tty1` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login with your user name and password, and run this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/
```

Now reboot (`sudo reboot`) and try to login as usually.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried it but didn't worked for me. it didn't give any error message either. After rebooting, the problem remains. It accepts my password, and goes 1 or 2 seconds blank and back to the log-in screen without showing any errors (like password incorrect).

Comment: @Srikanth Did yu changed $USER with the username that have this problem - aka 'XYZ'?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. yeah, I replaced it with my username. Anyway my problem solved now. I changed back to my previous password. Using the instructions given by Mr/Ms Mitch.

Comment: @Srikanth Ok, if his answer was usefull, you must to accept it.